# Abstract class and Interface instantiation performance in Java

Tags: java, performance, interface, abstract

Let's say I want to create a Button class, I have two options :

```
    abstract class Button {

        Button() { }

        abstract void action();
    }
```

When the button is pressed, action() will be called, in that case I would instantiate my Buttons like that :

```
    new Button() {
        void action() {
            ...
        }
    };
```

The other option is :

```
    interface ButtonAction {
        run();
    }
    class Button {

        ButtonAction action;

        Button(ButtonAction action) {
            this.action = action;
        }

    }
```

When the buttons is pressed, action.run() will be called, and I will instantiate the buttons like that :

```
    new Button(new ButtonAction() {
        void action() {
            ...
        }
    };
```

My question is, is there a bad and a good way, or it only depends on me? Is there a performance difference between those two buttons instantiation (I will often have to instantiate bunches of buttons)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not worry about micro optimizations of performance like this. This decision will not have any meaningful impact on your app peformane.

I would, however, use the section option where you pass in an action to the constructor for a few reasons. It decouples concerns. Your button object should not have to worry about the details of what action it has to perform. What if you want to add a setter to change the action? Then the abstract method option breaks down. The second option also makes it easier to test the action separately from the button. In general, favor delegation over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no very big performance difference for this cases. But you should remember, that abstract classes are used to hold common logic, i.e. you want to print some message after every action performing. If there's no common logic you should use interfaces.